# Buttons in ListView inside array adapter & fragment - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-adapter

I have an application that I am creating, in which there is a `Fragment` that contains a list view, this `ListView` is hosted in the main activity.

Each item in the list contains 10-20 buttons. How to have a click listener attached to them and perform actions when click, IE updating information on the screen?

EDIT: more information

Inside of listFragment:

```
public void myButtonHandler(View view){
//Handles method actions
}
```

inside of main activity:

```
public void myButtonHandler(View v){listFragment.myButtonHandler(v);

}
```

Error:

```
05-09 11:15:27.900    7122-7122/project.rapid.proto E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: project.rapid.proto, PID: 7122
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method myButtonHandler(View) in the activity class android.app.Application for onClick handler on view class android.widget.ImageButton with id 'required2'
```

The button clicks perform operations on information contained inside the fragments, thats why i attempted the call through.

Comment: Please read [ask]. What have you tried? What research have you done? Are you getting an error? Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

First things first:

1. Your ListView should be inside of your Fragment not your main activity.

As for your question:

Inside your custom array adapter you can set click listeners for each button to do what you want similar to:

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_CUSTOM_LAYOUT, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                // Set ViewHolder views to your custom views
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            // Set your different views via holder.yourView.setText(), etc.
            // Set your click listeners for the views you want via
            holder.myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    //Do what you want
                }

            });
            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: The list view is contained in the fragment. The listFragment you see in the main activity is a reference to the listFragment so that I can pass the click action through. Although its not functioning.

Comment: Then use an interface then. See: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the adapter-getView()
For example:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View v=super.getView(position, convertView, parent); 
    View clickView=v.findViewById(R.id.clickView);
    clickView.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: I think this may actually work for what i need it for. I'll try it out and respond.